# SPLIT xml in mutiple rows for RAISERROR insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, xml, triggers

The following code in my insert trigger returns the values all in a single row . If users are entering 1-10 rows at a time then that is fine but if they are entering 100s then the `raiserror` output becomes too long to read . What is the best solution for this please ?

TRIGGER CODE :

```
 DECLARE @level_name nvarchar(MAX) =
            (
            SELECT concat ([S_ID],'-', [l_NAME], '-')
             + '  '
            FROM inserted ic 
            where not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[LEVELS] c 
                  WHERE ic.[geo]=c.[GEO] and c.level_name=ic.[l_NAME] 
                            )
            FOR XML PATH('')
             );

        IF @level_name IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('level name not found: %s', 16, 1, @level_name) with log;
            END;
```

OUTPUT :

```
100-A2001 101-A2001 102-A2001 .......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you add a new line after each level ?

Comment: Thanks but how do I do that ?

Comment: is there a way to loop the `RAISERROR` ?

Comment: You can add a new line when concatenating the levels. 
For example: SELECT concat ([S_ID],'-', [l_NAME], '-', CHAR(13))...
CHAR(13) is the code for new line

Comment: JUst did that but then it adds this `100-&#x0D;SOA2001  101-&#x0D;SOA2001 ` and still in one single line

Comment: That is because you are using the FOR XML PATH(''). It converts the new line to characters. An alternative would be:
CREATE TABLE #MyStrings(value VARCHAR(MAX))
 ;
INSERT INTO #MyStrings
(
 value
)
VALUES
(
 'first'
),
(
 'second'
),
(
 'third'
)
;
DECLARE
 Result VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
 ;
SELECT
 Result = ISNULL(value,'') + ' ' + CHAR(13) + Result
FROM
 #MyStrings
 ;
SELECT
 Result
 ;
 
DROP TABLE #MyStrings;